# C# not receive full HTML in http request

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

I'm using this code to make a request to an HTML page:

```
public static String MakeHttpRequest(String url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I noticed that sometimes I receive from it not the full HTML code and only half of it(I recognize it by that sometimes the `responseString` is not full and does not include all the HTML)

Comment: how do you know its not full? is it a JS render site?

Comment: I can see that the HTML does not include the `body` and the `html` tags.

Comment: So you're only getting the `head` element?

Comment: @stuartd No, I can see the start of the body but not end, it's cut in the middle.

Comment: what url are you calling?  an internal one controlled by you or something not controlled by you?

Comment: @TMcKeown The URL is an `https://instagram.com`

Comment: your code looks fine...

Comment: either the sender is not flushing their response or you are mistaken...

Comment: the only difference I see with my own code is that I put the `StreamReader` in a using block.  but that doesn't make sense as a reason for what you describe.

Comment: assuming the site is using js rendering then it makes total sense that you will not receive the full html without js

Comment: Can you add the sample of not full response?

Comment: @Steve @T Mckeown Most of the times the call receive the full and the right HTML, but in some calls i receive half of it....

Comment: Just tested it with both HttpWebRequest and HttpClient (10 downloads each). The HTML page is fully downloaded. You might have a timeout issue or the UserAgent header is not set correctly. But, is this all the code you have for the request?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# HttpWebRequest Server not returning full response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432077/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-server-not-returning-full-response)