# StreamReader on occasion not receiving the entire response

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest, streamreader

I use the following method for receiving Web request responses.

```
private string SendRequest(string url)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (url != null && url.Length > 3 && url.EndsWith("xml"))
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
    else
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
    try
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helper.Log.Error(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have noticed that, on occasion (probably 1 out of 50 requests), this method does not return the entire response. This happens more often when the URL points to an XML file (e.g. https://www.mywebsite.com/thetargetfile.xml) or at least I am yet to experience a problem with other types of URL.

In an answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432077/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-server-not-returning-full-response), it's been mentioned that:

> [...] when you are using the same code on internet the servers does not
>   send all response data in one chunk, server could be busy processing
>   other requests or there could be some network latency, then, you
>   receive the response data in several chunks.

Is my `StreamReader` above likely to not receive the entire response? I have tested the responses on the Web browser and I seem to get the entire XML document.

Comment: A hint: Instead of `url.Length > 3 && url.Substring(url.Length - 3) == "xml"` you could just do `url.EndsWith("xml")`.